# Jquery Splitter bar 100% panel height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the jquery splitter plugin (first google hit) from here: https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.splitter

I have a sample code:

HTML:

```
<div id="widget">
    <div id="foo">
        Left Panel
    </div> 
    <div id="bar">
        right panel
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#widget {
        width: 400px;
        height: 100px;
    }

     #foo {
         background-color: #E92727;
         height: 1000px;
     }

    #bar {
        background-color: #BEE927;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

JS:

```
$('#widget').split({ orientation: 'vertical', limit: 100 });
```

This gives me following result:

[image]

Now I need both panels (left & right) to be always the same height, so the splitter bar reaches the very bottom. The content of both panels can grow dynamically.

Comment: any specific requirement to use plugin? I mean you do this by simple css, flexbox, column etc.

Comment: splitter allows dynamically resizing panels by dragging the splitter bar to the left or right

Comment: Google for Faux columns.

Comment: @MaryMelody : its not a duplicate! its a relevant and new question.

Answer (score 0):

Change `#widget`'s height to the tallest height between `#foo` and `#bar`

```
var foo = $('#foo').height();
var bar = $('#bar').height();

$('#widget').height( (foo > bar) ? foo : bar );
```

Comment: Since the content of both panels can dynamically grow I would prefer a CSS solution, so i don't have to execute JS code for resizing each time it happens.